# text box datas are not in symmetry

Tags: string, vb.net, fonts, textbox, symmetry

I created a list of dynamic text boxes in my vb.net program
then add  a row of data table in each text box
they are displaying like this:-

```
 M   20000
 s  4000
 j  3000
 M   3500
```

letter M is taking more pixels then s and j
how should I show it symmetryically

tried to change fonts and size of fonts in textbox property
but nothing worked

Comment: It depends on which fonts you tried - you need to use a "monospace" font such as Consolas or Courier where the width of M (an em) is the same as N (en) and L (el)

Comment: If you use a variable-width font, should it be a surprise that the characters are various widths? If you want character widths to be fixed, you need to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: thanks chill60 and jmcilhinney monospace font consolas solved the proble